# Concatenating multiple dataframe columns into a single array under a dataframe column

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to concatenate multiple columns(all are numeric number) in a dataframe into an array under one single column of a dataframe. Caveat is if the concatenating columns have NAN, then should not be concatenated.

**Input dataframe**:

```
userid | p1 | p2 |p3 | p4 | p5
 1     | NAN| NAN| 20| 30 | 40
 1     | NAN| 30 | 60| 80 | 100
 2     | NAN| NAN|NAN| NAN| 45
```

I have tried this solution but it doesnt drop the nan:

```
df['combined'] = df[['p5','p4','p3','p2','p1']].apply(tuple,axis=1).apply(np.array)
```

**Final Output** dataframe must look like this(also the order of concatenation is p5,p4,p3,p2,p1) while also excluding nan while concatenating:

```
userid | p1 | p2 |p3 | p4 | p5 | combined
 1     | NAN| NAN| 20| 30 | 40 | [40,30,20]
 1     | NAN| 30 | 60| 80 | 100| [100,80,60,30]
 2     | NAN| NAN|NAN| NAN| 45 | [45]
```

So any solution for the above output will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [pd.isna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html) to filter out the `NaN` values with *boolean mask*:

```
df['combined'] = df[['p5', 'p4', 'p3', 'p2', 'p1']].apply(lambda x: x[~pd.isna(x)].values, axis=1)
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
   userid  p1    p2    p3    p4   p5                   combined
0       1 NaN   NaN  20.0  30.0   40         [40.0, 30.0, 20.0]
1       1 NaN  30.0  60.0  80.0  100  [100.0, 80.0, 60.0, 30.0]
2       2 NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   45                     [45.0]
```

As mentioned by @jpp, you could also drop them, by using [dropna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dropna.html#pandas.Series.dropna):

```
lambda x: x.dropna().values
```

Comment: Or `df.iloc[:, 1:].apply(lambda x: x.dropna().tolist(), axis=1)` ?

Comment: @Daniel - Thanks you for your solution provided, this worked for me

Comment: @Datta glad I could help. Please consider marking this answer as accepted as it will signal others that your problem was solved.